# Accessing compositeData client side

Tags: xpages

I have a custom control that has a property defined that I need to access in a client side script.

Is there a simple way to access compositeData client side?

Comment: Found the answer in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568519/getting-to-scope-varibles-in-client-side-javascript-csjs-on-xpages

Basically, set up a client side var in a scriptBlock tag.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your own comment you can generate a piece of script using a scriptblock. Another way is to use a xp:inputHidden with the value #{compositeData.yourpropertyname}. When using the scriptblock approach be aware that the generated code also generates a unique var name which you can identify.

this is to prevent multiple instances of the same custom control to overide the same javascript variable.